# How to deserialize a nested json string?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json, jsonserializer

Suppose I have this classes:

```
internal class Test
{
    public string value { get; set; }

    public Test(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Response<T>
{
    private string errorMessage { get; }
    private T returnValue { get;  }

    public Response(string errorMessage, T returnValue)
    {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.returnValue = returnValue;
    }

    public bool HasError() { return errorMessage != ""; }

    public bool AssertEqualsReturnValue(object obj) { return returnValue.Equals(obj); }
        
}
```

and I have this Main function:

```
string json = 
@"{
    ""errorMessage"": ""This is an error"",
    ""returnValue"": {
        ""value"": ""this is what returns""
    }
}
";

Response<Test> r = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response<Test>>(json); ;
Console.WriteLine(r.AssertEqualsReturnValue("this is what returns"));
Console.WriteLine(r.HasError());
```

I get the next error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'IntroSE.Kanban.Backend.Response`1[ConsoleApp1.Test]' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.'

It won't desirialize because I need to somehow tell the JsonSerializer I have a **Test** object in **returnValue** key.
I saw some solutions online but the problem is they all use JsonConverter which is no in use anymore in .Net 6.0.

Comment: Have you tried to decorate your `Response` class's constructor with the [`JsonConstructor` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0)? And the same should be applied for `Test`'s ctor.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, it doesn't work :\

Comment: Does it throw some exception? Or the deserialized value is null? Or ??

Comment: @PeterCsala I have added the error message to the question body now, it says the keys do not much but they clearly do

Comment: You receive that exception because `errorMessage` and `returnValue` are declared as `private`.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks! that solved it!

Comment: shall I leave a post with the solution?

Comment: @PeterCsala I got the idea but I think it will benefit others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `errorMessage` and `returnValue` properties with `private` visibility. If you change them to `public` after that the exception will not be thrown.

Please be aware that the `JsonInclude` attribute can be used only in case of non-public property accessors, like `private set;` or `private get;`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI
you can do this in VS

1. copy the json

   {
   "errorMessage": "This is an error",
   "returnValue": {
   "value": "this is what returns"
   }
   }
2. Choose EDIT < Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes
   [image]
3. Check and compare with your classes

[image]